# MATLAB: Find largest singular values of a matrix and corresponding singular vectors

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, svd

I have matrix `A` and matrices `[U,S,V]`, such that `[U, S, V] = svd(A)`.

How could I amend my script in matlab to get the 10 columns of `U` that correspond to the 10 largest singular values of `A` (i.e. the largest values in `S`)?

Comment: The singular values in `S` are already ordered largest to smallest. You would just take the first 10 columns of `U`.

Comment: @eigenchris - Yup! lol.  I just wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you recall the definition of the `svd`, it is essentially solving an eigenvalue problem such that:

```
Av = su
```

`v` is a right-eigenvector from the matrix `V` and `u` is a left-eigenvector from the matrix `U`.  `s` is a singular value from the matrix `S`.  You know that `S` is a diagonal matrix where these are the singular values sorted in descending order.  As such, if we took the first column of `v` and the first column of `u`, as well as the first singular value of `s` (top-left corner), if we did the above computation, we should get both outputs to be the same.

As an example:

```
rng(123);
A = randn(4,4);
[U,S,V] = svd(A);

format long;
o1 = A*V(:,1);
o2 = S(1,1)*U(:,1);

disp(o1);
disp(o2);

 -0.267557887773137
  1.758696945035771
  0.934255531699997
 -0.978346339659143

 -0.267557887773136
  1.758696945035771
  0.934255531699996
 -0.978346339659143
```

Similarly, if we looked at the second columns of `U` and `V` with the second singular value:

```
o1 = A*V(:,2);
o2 = S(2,2)*U(:,2);
disp(o1);
disp(o2);

 0.353422275717823
-0.424888938462465
 1.543570300948254
 0.613563185406719

 0.353422275717823
-0.424888938462465
 1.543570300948252
 0.613563185406719
```

As such, the basis vectors are arranged such that the columns are arranged from left to right in the same order as what the singular values dictate.  As such, you simply grab the first 10 columns of `U`.  This can be done by:

```
out = U(:,1:10);
```

`out` would contain the basis vectors, or columns of `U` that correspond to the 10 highest singular values of `A`.

Comment: thank you very much - was failing to fully realize the definition of svd.

Answer (score 0):

First you sort the singular values, and save the reindexing, then take the first 10 values:

```
[a, b]=sort(diag(S));
Umax10=U(:,b(1:10));
```

As mentioned by [Rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng), `svd` outputs the singular values in decreasing order so:

```
Umax10=U(:,1:10);
```

is enough.

Just have to remember that it is not the case for `eig`, even though it may seems that `eig` also outputs ordered eigenvalues it is not always the case.

Comment: `S` is already ordered.  There is no need to sort it.  It is actually a diagonal matrix where the diagonal entries are sorted.

Comment: @rayryeng you are right, I knew `eig` didn't provide sorted eigenvalues and I thought `svd` was the same but I was mistaken

Comment: Yes you are correct about `eig`.  I can see why you got confused :)  I usually don't use `eig` in favour of `svd` as it's more stable.

Comment: yes more stable but it can also be quite slower, always a tradeoff :)